# Hamburger navigation, how to hide/show links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navbar

So I have a navbar with an animated hamburger, and when I click the hamburger I want to display the navigation links, which are hidden by default.

How do I include the closeNav function on the hamburger when its an X? If I just insert it behind the openNav function then nothing shows up at all, so thats obviously not the right way.

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("navbar--middle").style.display = "block";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("navbar--middle").style.display = "none";
}

function myFunction(x) {
    x.classList.toggle("change");
}
```

```css
.navbar--middle {
  display: none;
  margin-left: 26%;
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  & a {
    display: inline-flex;
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  }
}

.hamburger {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 45px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.icon1 {
 width: 35px;
 height: 5px;
 background-color: black;
 margin: 6px 0;
 border-radius: 5px;
 transition: 0.4s;
}
.icon2 {
 width: 35px;
 height: 5px;
 background-color: black;
 margin: 6px 0;
 border-radius: 5px;
 transition: 0.4s;
}
.icon3 {
 width: 35px;
 height: 5px;
 background-color: black;
 margin: 6px 0;
 border-radius: 5px;
 transition: 0.4s;
}

/* Rotate first bar */
.change .icon1 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px) ;
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px) ;
}

/* Fade out the second bar */
.change .icon2 {
    opacity: 0;
}

/* Rotate last bar */
.change .icon3 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px) ;
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px) ;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar--middle" id="navbar--middle">
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#" id="btn--toepassing">Toepassing</a>
  <a href="#" id="btn--specificaties">Specificaties</a>
  <a href="#" id="btn--referenties">Referenties</a>
  <a href="#" id="btn--container--dealers">Dealers</a>
</div>

  <div class="navbar--right">
    <div class="hamburger" id="hamburger" onclick="openNav(); myFunction(this)">
      <div class="icon1"></div>
      <div class="icon2"></div>
      <div class="icon3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This is not the way I would do it, but it seems to work (at least for the open part). What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put the **if else** condition of **`element.style.display`** like below

```js
var hamburger = document.getElementById('hamburger');
var menu = document.getElementById('navbar--middle');
menu.style.display = "none";
hamburger.addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.classList.toggle("change");
  if (menu.style.display === "none") {
    menu.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    menu.style.display = "none";
  }
})
```

```css
.navbar--middle {
  display: none;
  margin-left: 26%;
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
}

.navbar--middle a {
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
}

.hamburger {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 45px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.icon1 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 6px 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.icon2 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 6px 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.icon3 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 6px 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}


/* Rotate first bar */

.change .icon1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}


/* Fade out the second bar */

.change .icon2 {
  opacity: 0;
}


/* Rotate last bar */

.change .icon3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar--middle" id="navbar--middle">
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#" id="btn--toepassing">Toepassing</a>
  <a href="#" id="btn--specificaties">Specificaties</a>
  <a href="#" id="btn--referenties">Referenties</a>
  <a href="#" id="btn--container--dealers">Dealers</a>
</div>

<div class="navbar--right">
  <div class="hamburger" id="hamburger">
    <div class="icon1"></div>
    <div class="icon2"></div>
    <div class="icon3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to include the state of the navbar in the class, usually this is done with `open` and `close` then once you click the hamburger button you can check to see the current state and execute the appropriate code.

https://api.jquery.com/addclass/

https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/

Answer (score 0):

Why not add a class open, which you toggle in the 'myFunction' you have.
And set the style to display:block for that class?

Comment: Yeah, pretty new to stackoverflow, was trying to get it in there. but i couldn't seem to edit the javascript part.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("navbar--middle").style.display = "block";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("navbar--middle").style.display = "none";
}

function myFunction(x) {
    x.classList.toggle("change");
    if(x.classList.contains("change")) {
     openNav();
    } else {
     closeNav();
    }
}
```

```css
.navbar--middle {
  display: none;
  margin-left: 26%;
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  & a {
    display: inline-flex;
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  }
}

.hamburger {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 45px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.icon1 {
 width: 35px;
 height: 5px;
 background-color: black;
 margin: 6px 0;
 border-radius: 5px;
 transition: 0.4s;
}
.icon2 {
 width: 35px;
 height: 5px;
 background-color: black;
 margin: 6px 0;
 border-radius: 5px;
 transition: 0.4s;
}
.icon3 {
 width: 35px;
 height: 5px;
 background-color: black;
 margin: 6px 0;
 border-radius: 5px;
 transition: 0.4s;
}

/* Rotate first bar */
.change .icon1 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px) ;
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px) ;
}

/* Fade out the second bar */
.change .icon2 {
    opacity: 0;
}

/* Rotate last bar */
.change .icon3 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px) ;
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px) ;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar--middle" id="navbar--middle">
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#" id="btn--toepassing">Toepassing</a>
  <a href="#" id="btn--specificaties">Specificaties</a>
  <a href="#" id="btn--referenties">Referenties</a>
  <a href="#" id="btn--container--dealers">Dealers</a>
</div>

  <div class="navbar--right">
    <div class="hamburger" id="hamburger" onclick="myFunction(this)">
      <div class="icon1"></div>
      <div class="icon2"></div>
      <div class="icon3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off simply toggling a class (on a parent element) on click with javascript. Transitions should be handled by CSS and by having a single parent class toggle you can use 1 class to handle all style changes.

Also take note of the z-index on the hamburger icon. This rule keeps the icon on the highest layer and clickable at all times.

```js
function toggleNav() {
  document.getElementById("body-id").classList.toggle('nav-toggle-class');
}
```

```css
.navbar--middle {
  padding-top: 80px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: red;
  
   opacity: 0;
   pointer-events: none;
   transform: translateX(-100%);
   transition: all 0.4s ease; 
}

body.nav-toggle-class .navbar--middle {
   opacity: 1;
   pointer-events: all;
   transform: translateX(0);
}


.hamburger {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: fixed;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.icon1 {
 width: 35px;
 height: 5px;
 background-color: black;
 margin: 6px 0;
 border-radius: 5px;
 transition: 0.4s;
}
.icon2 {
 width: 35px;
 height: 5px;
 background-color: black;
 margin: 6px 0;
 border-radius: 5px;
 transition: 0.4s;
}
.icon3 {
 width: 35px;
 height: 5px;
 background-color: black;
 margin: 6px 0;
 border-radius: 5px;
 transition: 0.4s;
}

/* Rotate first bar */
.nav-toggle-class .icon1 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px) ;
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px) ;
}

/* Fade out the second bar */
.nav-toggle-class .icon2 {
    opacity: 0;
}

/* Rotate last bar */
.nav-toggle-class .icon3 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px) ;
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px) ;
}

  .navbar--middle a {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  }
```

```html
<body id="body-id" class="">

<div class="navbar--middle" id="navbar--middle">
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#" id="btn--toepassing">Toepassing</a>
  <a href="#" id="btn--specificaties">Specificaties</a>
  <a href="#" id="btn--referenties">Referenties</a>
  <a href="#" id="btn--container--dealers">Dealers</a>
</div>

  <div class="navbar--right">
    <div class="hamburger" id="hamburger" onclick="toggleNav();">
      <div class="icon1"></div>
      <div class="icon2"></div>
      <div class="icon3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could toggle a class on both the menu and the hamburger, and adjust the styles in your CSS instead.

example...

```js
var navbarBurger = document.getElementById('hamburger');

navbarBurger.addEventListener('click', function() {

  var menu = document.getElementById("navbar--middle");

  navbarBurger.classList.toggle('is-active');
  menu.classList.toggle('is-active');

});
```

```css
.navbar--middle {
  display: none;
  margin-left: 26%;
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  & a {
    display: inline-flex;
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  }
}

.navbar--middle.is-active {
  display: block;
}

.hamburger {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 45px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.icon1 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 6px 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.icon2 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 6px 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.icon3 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 6px 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}


/* Rotate first bar */

.is-active .icon1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}


/* Fade out the second bar */

.is-active .icon2 {
  opacity: 0;
}


/* Rotate last bar */

.is-active .icon3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar--middle" id="navbar--middle">
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#" id="btn--toepassing">Toepassing</a>
  <a href="#" id="btn--specificaties">Specificaties</a>
  <a href="#" id="btn--referenties">Referenties</a>
  <a href="#" id="btn--container--dealers">Dealers</a>
</div>

<div class="navbar--right">
  <div class="hamburger" id="hamburger">
    <div class="icon1"></div>
    <div class="icon2"></div>
    <div class="icon3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```